# How to extract a Date from an SQLDateTime object in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sqldatetime

I am trying to do a plot of a time series with `DateListPlot`.  I want to feed it a time series I obtain from an SQL database.  When I retrieve the time series the list is composed of `SQLDateTime` entries that `DateListPlot` doesn't understand.

`In[24]:= t=SQLExecute[conn, "select timestamp,value from timeseries order by timestamp asc"]`

`Out[24]={{SQLDateTime[{2010,1,1}],12.3},{SQLDateTime[{2010,1,2}],12.51}}`

Doesn't work:
`In[25]:= DateListPlot[t]`

`DateListPlot` requires a Date tuple and doesn't understand SQLDateTime.  What can I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer:

```
In[1]:= SQLDateTime[{2001, 5, 7}][[1]]
Out[1]:= {2001,5,7}
```

Mathematica thinks of everything very similarly internally. What you see as `{1, 2, 3}` is actually `List[1,2,3]`. The Part function (denoted by `[[...]]`) works just as well on any function, not just `List`.

The quick and dirty way to apply this in your case:

```
{#[[1,1]],#[[2]]}& /@ SQLExecute[...]
```

Comment: It might be more efficient and clear to do something like `SQLExecute[...] /. SQLDateTime[l_]:>l` or `SQLExecute[...] /. SQLDateTime -> Identity` when you have multiple columns of `SQLDateTime` objects. Also, `DateListPlot` understands integer Unix-style timestamps, so you could replace `SQLDateTime` with `AbsoluteTime` to convert to those, since `AbsoluteTime[{timespec...}]` gives you a timestamp.

Comment: Yeah, I did call it quick and dirty. Using a rule is definitely more clear, and more efficient in terms of amount of code. I'm not sure if a rule is in general faster, though, because it has to search through everything, while if you know the structure of your data, you can use something like this which doesn't have to examine anything except the places you know SQLDateTime occurs.